# will_paginate and inherited_resources don't work together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, inherited-resources

Will paginate (3.0.3) doesn't work with inherited resources (1.3.1). In my controller:

```
protected
def collection
  @posts ||= end_of_association_chain.paginate(:page => params[:page])
end
```

I added require 'will_paginate/array' in my initializer, but this doesn't fix the problem. How can i get working will paginate and inherited resources together? In my views i get error

```
undefined method `total_pages' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000004312e38>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is kind of a long shot, but I ran into this problem and it turns out it was CanCan, another gem I am using.  This was one of the first things I stumbled on, so I figured it may help someone one day.

Check out: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Inherited-Resources

The call to `load_and_authorize_resource` loads the collection so the right side of the conditional assignment never gets run in the `collection` method.  The fix that is described in the link above is to skip authorization for collection actions, and do the check explicitly in the `collection` method.

```
skip_load_and_authorize_resource :only => :index

protected

def collection
  @posts ||= end_of_association_chain.accessible_by(current_ability).paginate(:page => params[:page])
end
```

I hope that helps someone.